# What kind of ASP.NET Web Site project i should choose?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, twilio

I want to build a web application using Azure.
The service will be call MessagingService.
The service need also use Twilio rest to execute automated voice messages.
The service will have one client that will send him HTTP post data request.
The service will need to translate that request to messages and make an out-bounded calls using Twilio rest. I need that my service will have a domain name because that what Twilio demand to use there service. I want also that the service can perform auto scaling. At first I want to build this app using ASP.NET MVC but I cannot see the need of using view at my service because it is just needed to do some background tasks so i don't now how to build it because MVC is model view controller and I dont need view for this? My limitation is that I need it will have a domain that I can use Twilio. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

sounds to me you want a WEB api v2. With the build-in publish method from VS, you can easily publish to azure, or choose for CI/CD with Jenkins for example. With azure you can handle the scale out (more instances) or scale up (more resources). This has no impact for you choice of API.

Have you looked at .NET core? You have a lot of standard built-in function with DI etc.

Comment: Hi Roelant thanks for the quick response. If i create WEB api v2 it will have a domain name that i can use it with Twilio?

Comment: no. The type of application you create, has nothing to do with any domainname. You can create a A or CName, of on-premise a DNS record to point to the right domain. Your network guys will know what to do :)

Comment: If I build WEB api v2 and deploy it to azure it will be in azure virtual machine and not on azure website? it can peform auto scale?

Comment: @ozsh83, azure virtual machines can be scaled, but that also depends on what you mean by scaling. See [Automatic scaling and virtual machine scale sets](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-overview/) for more details. But why bother with the complication of managing the servers, any ASP.NET application (which includes WEB api v2) can be deployed to a [Azure Cloud Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cloud-services/) (formerly Azure Websites), where all of that is taken care for you.

Comment: Agree @Adrian, excatly! don't go there if you don't need to  :)

Comment: Thanks a lot(: can you send me link to how deploy my WEB api v2 to azure cloud service? you means that i can build standard asp.net web app and after just deploy it to Azure?

Comment: Best place to start with Azure Cloud Services is here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/learning-paths/cloud-services/ which also covers deployment.

Comment: Please stop turning this into a discussion, especially in comments - this isn't the place.

Comment: @Adrian - that's incorrect: Cloud Services is *not* the same as Websites - that would be Web Apps. Two very different things.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, ah yes quite right. I did actually meant [App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-overview/). Microsoft's Azure stack is rapidly changing as well at is naming.

Comment: .NET core work with twilio? i cannot add TwiMl to my project.

Comment: you can actually reference it as a .net framework. In essence it would be the same as a 'normal' project from .net framework.
In your project.json you need to reference (in framework): net461 if .net core is not available for twello. Don't know that actually.

Comment: you can tell me where exactly in project.json? change to net461?